# Change negative values to zero using for loop

Tags: r

I should solve this problem with R, but I'm not really familiar with it so how to solve it?

> A vector of length 10 called " vec " has been defined. Write a for
> loop that changes every negative element of vec to a zero.

How do I do this? I've tried this sort of things but it doesn't work.

```
x <- 0
 for(var in 1:10){
  if  (vec x < 0) <- 0
}
```

Comment: What do you think ``vec x`` is doing?

Comment: no need of `for` loop `vec[vec < 0] <- 0`

Comment: Try `for(i in seq_along(vec)) if(vec[i] < 0) vec[i] <- 0`

Comment: I don't understand why teachers want students to use R as if it's C. What's the point?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for (i in 1:length(vec)){
  vec[i] = replace(vec[i], vec[i]<0, 0)
}
```